# lazy / defer images without JS or with, but with a good(not loaded) JS-Fallback

Tags: javascript, html, performance, css, asynchronous

I'm trying to make the load of a website as efficient as it may get and want to load most of the images asynchronously or in such a way it won't block content from loading.

I'm looking for a good none-javascript, cross-browser solution for this matter, or with pure javascript, but with a good fallback script(the `<noscript>` as far as I know, not a good solution as some browsers still load the content from it even if the JS is enabled).